# Spring and JMS Integration Configuration file error

Tags: java, spring, jms

I keep having this error when I'm trying to integrate Spring JMS into my current project. It's driving me up the wall and I'm not entirely sure how to fix it as I'm new to Spring.

```
The prefix "jms" for element "jms:listener-container" is not bound.
```

The code in question is this,

```
<jms:listener-container container-type="default" connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="auto"> 

<jms:listener destination="TESTQUEUE" ref="simpleMessageListener" method="onMessage" /> 

</jms:listener-container>
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the jms: namespace but I don't know how to fix it as before my program was complaining about the p: namespace so I had to change it to property name="some value" reference="someReference"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have the jms namespace in your context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd">

<!-- <bean/> definitions here -->

</beans>
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html for details.